# About Regular Expressions

Tags: python, regex

```
import re

line = 'Here is my probblem, brother!'

t = re.findall('..b', line)

print(t)
```

This prints:

```
['rob', ', b']
```

But it should find 'obb' in 'probblem'. Why?

Comment: `findall` returns all *non-overlapping* matches.

Comment: `.` matches any char that is not line break

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `.` will match one character, and in this case you have `'ro'` and  `', '` which are followed by one `b`. And with regards to this point that `finall()` function doesn't match overlapped patterns if you want to match such patterns, you can use a [positive look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and put your pattern in a capture group :

```
>>> t = re.findall('(?=(..b))', line)
>>> t
['rob', 'obb', ', b']
```